# Using regexes in grep function in R

Tags: regex, r

Could anyone maybe know how to extract `x` and `y` from this character: `"x and y"` using `grep` function (not using `stringi` package) if `x` and `y` are random characters?
I am so not skilled in regular expressions.
Thanks for any response.

Comment: Well, `grep` matches an entire string, not parts of a string. So if you want to extract both `x` and `y`, that's probably not the right function. Are the two values you are interested in always separated by " and "? If do, using `strsplit` probably makes more sense. For example: `strsplit("x and y", " and ")[[1]]`

Comment: @MrFlick, I have a feeling that `and` is just an example and he looks for a more general solution. But I may be wrong though

Comment: @MrFlick thanks! This is always separated by " and " what is a result of `htest.object$data.name`

Comment: @DavidArenburg as i read it, the "and" seems constant and the "x" and "y" are random. It's impossible to write useful code that needs to be generalizeable with exactly one (bad) sample input. Hopefully the OP can provide more useful test cases.

Comment: @MrFlick, yeah it seems you are right according to his comment. Oh well...

Answer (score 4):

The regex here matches any chars "and" chars and then extracts them with `regmatches`:

```
txt <- c("x and y", "a and  b", " C and d", "qq and rr")

matches <- regexec("([[:alpha:]]+)[[:blank:]]+and[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)", txt)

regmatches(txt, matches)[[1]][2:3]
## [1] "x" "y"

regmatches(txt, matches)[[2]][2:3]
## [1] "a" "b"

regmatches(txt, matches)[[3]][2:3]
## [1] "C" "d"

regmatches(txt, matches)[[4]][2:3]
## [1] "qq" "rr"
```

`([[:alpha:]]+)` matches one or more alpha characters and places it in a match group. `[[:blank:]]+` matches one or more "whitespace" characters. There are less verbose ways to write these regexes but the expanded ones (to me) help make it easier to grok if there will be folks reading the code that aren't familiar with regexes.

I also didn't need to call `regmatches` 4x, but it was faster to cut/paste for a toy example.

Answer (score 4):

As @MrFlick commented, `grep` is not the right function to extract these substrings.

You can use `regmatches` and do something like this:

```
> x <- c('x and y', 'abc and def', 'foo and bar')
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('and(*SKIP)(*F)|\\w+', x, perl=T))
# [[1]]
# [1] "x" "y"

# [[2]]
# [1] "abc" "def"

# [[3]]
# [1] "foo" "bar"
```

Or if `" and "` is always constant, then use `strsplit` as suggested in the comments.

```
> x <- c('x and y', 'abc and def', 'foo and bar')
> strsplit(x, ' and ', fixed=T)
# [[1]]
# [1] "x" "y"

# [[2]]
# [1] "abc" "def"

# [[3]]
# [1] "foo" "bar"
```